# Unable to uninstall SQL Server Integration Services Projects Extension

Tags: windows-10, sql-server, ssis

I installed SQL server, then SSDT from VS installer and after that the SSIS Extension v3.0 for VS Community 2019. But now that I try to uninstall it I get the following error:

> Some components will not be uninstalled because removing them would place this computer in an unsupported state. Please manually remove them in Control Panel.

After that I get the following message:

> The configuration registry database is corrupt (0x800703F1)

Answer (score 1):

Try known issue #6 [here at Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects):

> Cannot be uninstalled from Control Panel. 
>   Here is a work around:
>
> - Open extension.vsixmanifest under `<VSInstanceRootDir>\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS`,
> - Change the value of attribute `InstalledByMsi` at line 10
>     from "true" to "false",
> - Save extension.vsixmanifest,
>
> and then you can uninstall this product from Control Panel.